# When using RandomAccessFile and Multi Thread, How do I split big char file?

Tags: java

I have to read a big char file.Then I have found `RandomAccessFile` which meets my need. I have a try, then faced with a question that how to get the point that every thread starts with.

The RandomAccessFile API read file by byte, but the file is charset and I need to process every line.so How do I spilt it by line ?

thanks help.

Can not do this with NIO.

Comment: I find your question unclear, but what's wrong with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readLine%28%29 and be careful using RandomAccessFile in a multi-threaded environment, because it's not thread safe.

Comment: @luc14n0 I just want to use multi thread read a file, every thread has a start and end point.

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying read multiple parts of the file in parallel, but you want to read **lines** in parallel. This is not possible, unless the entire file is read before, because `RandomAccessFile` lets you read bytes by offset, and if you don't know the offset of each `\n` you have to read the entire file before, and reading it in parallel after finding all `\n` makes no sense at all, as you already read the file to find `\n` offsets and you would read it again slowing down the app

Comment: thank you very much! Yes, you understand what I want to say.@BackSlash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to read a big `char` file.

So you should be using `FileReader`, probably wrapped in a `BufferedReader`.

However reading a file with multiple threads won't buy you anything. The disk isn't multi-threaded.

And you can't read lines in parallel. It doesn't even make sense,

Comment: but using FileReader limit the thread num to one. I have to use multi thread to speed.

Comment: I've already addressed that. You can read millions of lines a second with `BufferedReader.readLine()`.

Comment: I want to be faster than `BufferedReader.readLine()`, so I try to use multi thread. But it seems no effective.